# Tomcat: Filter log4j by logger name

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j, verbosity

I am working with an external package which uses a log4j quite verbosely. I've looked at the code and found the expected `log4j` lines:

```java
private Logger log = Logger.getLogger("SomeLoggerName");
...
log.info("Trivial message");
log.info("More trivial data");
```

Since I can't change the code, I've tried to change `log4j.xml`:

```xml
<category name="SomeLoggerName">
  <level value="${log4j_level:-WARN}"/>
  <appender-ref ref="FileLogger"/>
</category>
```

I guessed that`category name` property is equivalent to the logger name. Is it true? If not, how can I filter by logger name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, logger == category. Do you have problems with your configuration? Generally it looks OK and should work.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't tried it yet, but I wanted to a. make sure I'm right before deploying, and b. have a verified answer published online.

Answer (score 4):

If you're just looking to turn down verbosity, I'd just turn up the priority level:

```
<category name="SomeLoggerName">
  <level value="WARN"/>
</category>
```

Otherwise, you might want to add a [filter](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/Filter.html) to your existing appender.  First, implement a log4j filter.  In your case it would be a simple comparison to determine whether or not the log event was from the unwanted class.  Something like this would work:

```
public class MyAuditFilter extends Filter{

    @Override
    public int decide(LoggingEvent event) {
        if(event.getClass.getCanonicalName().equalsIgnoreCase("class.you.don't.want"))
            return Filter.DENY;
        else
            return Filter.ACCPET;
    }
}
```

Once you have your filter implemented, just add it to your log4j appender like so:

```
<appender name="myAppender" class="my.appender.class">
  .
  .
  <filter class="my.namespace.MyAuditFilter">
    <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="True"/>
  </filter>
  .
  .
</appender>
```

If you need more control, the filter will be able to give you extremely fine-grained control over your logging.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can use `<logger>` as an element name, e.g.

```
<logger name="SomeLoggerName">
  <level value="${log4j_level:-WARN}"/>
  <appender-ref ref="FileLogger"/>
</logger>
```

I think `category` is there for backward compatibility and its use is deprecated.