# Can I configure Log4j using Tomcat Context Parameters?

Tags: java, log4j, tomcat6

I want to be able to log at different levels depending on what server I deploy my Java web application on. For example, on my test server I would like to log at the DEBUG level and on my production server I would like to log at the WARN level. Currently my log4.xml file is located inside of my WAR file. I want to be able to configure the logging level of my web app using Tomcat context parameters. Is this possible?

I have seen that environment variables and system properties can be used. For example, **${catalina.home}** gets interpreted. Is this same functionality available for substituting in Tomcat context parameter values?

For example, this would be the log4j.xml snippet:

```
<level value="${log.level}"
```

Where **log.level** is defined in %TOMCAT_HOME%/conf/context.xml:

```
<Parameter name="log.level" value="DEBUG" />
```

I have tried the above and it does not seem to work. Google has not turned up anything for me related to using context parameters in log4j configuration files. I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201188/364029) doing something similar using system properties, but it does not use Tomcat context parameters so it is not quite what I want. Is a context parameter value substitution capability available in log4j configuration? Do I need to explore other options such using an external log4j.xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that Log4J does this natively.  I recall that the Spring Web Framework came with a listener configured via web.xml that might do something a little similar.  If you really wanted to, I think you could could grab the code for that and use it to create something that does exactly want you want.

Comment: We ended up using an external log configuration file using [Log4jWebConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/Log4jWebConfigurer.html) and the log4jConfigLocation property with a file value such as file:/path/to/log4j.xml. Later on we decided to switch to Logback and we used Spring Extensions for Logback, which has a similar property called logbackConfigLocation. This allows us to use different config files for the different environments we deploy to.

Answer (score 0):

One method I've been using recently for extremely fine-grained control over logging is the log4 [appender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Appender.html).  It's a little more work than editing your config file, but gives you an incredible amount of flexibility.  See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722440/tomcat-filter-log4j-by-logger-name/11722820#11722820) for a quick example on how one of these would be configured.